# exclude folder in a filesMatch in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web

I have a .htaccess with:

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$|\.js$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

How can I exclude a subdirectory?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You can not exclude folders using filesMatch , use mod-rewrite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder_to_exclude
RewriteRule \.(php|js)$ - [H=application/x-httpd-php]
```

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately this makes my site go into "internal server error" mode

Comment: i used absolute and relative path to my folder

Comment: Ok, in my subdirectory there was another htaccess that caused the 505 error. It is working now. Thanks!